# C: String erroneously printing twice

Tags: c, string, printf

I'm playing around with C strings as in the following programme:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    
    char *player1  = "Harry";
    char player2[] = "Rosie";
    char player3[6] = "Ronald";

    printf("%s %s %s\n", player1, player2, player3);
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints the following:

```
Harry Rosie RonaldRosie
```

Why is "Rosie" printing out twice?

Comment: Cause strings in C always end with a nul byte, your `player3` array should be 7 bytes and not 6.

Comment: You forgot to leave room for the terminator in the `Ronald` literal, so printing continues into the following variable, which happens to be `Rosie` here.

Comment: It must be `char player3[7] = "Ronald";` to hold the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behavior

Comment: `player3` not  contain a _string_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ronald` has 6 letters, so `char player3[6]` leaves no space for the null-terminator character `'\0'`.

In your case, it printed whatever comes after `Ronald` in memory until a `'\0'` was encountered. That happened to be `Rosie`. You might not always be so lucky and run into an error (e.g. memory protection) before finding a `'\0'`.

One solution (apart from how you initialized `Harry` and `Rosie`) is to increase the number of elements by one to provide space for a trailing `'\0'`:

```c
char player3[7] = "Ronald";
```

Comment: Note that it is also possible to simply write `char players3[] = "Ronald"`, which automatically makes the array the shortest possible length for holding the string literal **including** the terminating null character.

Comment: "Therefore, it will print whatever comes after Ronald in memory until it finds a \0." is one of many possibilities as it is _undeifned behavior_ to use `"%s"` with a non-_string_.

Comment: yes, it's not guaranteed to run trouble free. I referred to OP's example.